Allow user to input numbers only no special character or alphabet in Angular text box
I have an input field where the requirement is that it has 0 initially set. On change of value that 0 is removed and a number is added, but that 0 is removed only if the key pressed by the user is a number.
Now the issue arises that when I do use an input event it takes my value as sing quoted string as '8'. I had used the replace method, but if I press backspace also on focus out it adds a .00 to a number if its there.
I also found a issue when my number is initially 0 and I press a non-numeric value, it makes my number set to ''. Also on backspace keypress it should allow backspace and remove 0. It should not give an error when I remove the last non-0 number after typing something and do a backspace, but it gives an error Cannot read properties of null (reading 'replace'). That is also a case, so its a mix of various cases.
<input type="text" class="someclass" [readOnly]="isView || isEdit" placeholder=""
    formControlName="somename" mask="separator.2" thousandSeparator="," 
    (input)="removeZeroOnKeydown($event)" (focusout)="onFixedAmount('somename')" 
    separatorLimit="99999999999999">
    <label class="label">Some Label$</label>

removeZeroOnKeydown(event: InputEvent) {
    let inputElement = event.target as HTMLInputElement;

    //Get FormControl Name on keydown
    let controlName = inputElement.getAttribute('formControlName');
    
    if (!controlName) return;

    let control = this.myformname.controls[controlName];

    //Check Formcontrol input field value
    let controlValue = control.value;

    // If the input field only contains "0", replace it with the input data
    if (controlValue == 0 || controlValue == '') {

    //Get the keypressed value
    let inputData = (event as InputEvent).data;

    //let numberValue = inputData.replace(/'/g, "");
    
    if (inputData && /^\d$/.test(inputData.replace(/'/g, ""))) {

      //Set value of keypressed
      control.setValue(inputData);
    }
    else {
        if(controlValue == 0 && controlValue){
            control.setValue(0);
        }
        else if(!/^\d$/.test(inputData.replace(/'/g, "")) && controlValue != 0) {
          control.setValue('');
        }
    }
}

onFixedAmount(FormControlName) {
    let amount = this.myformname.controls[FormControlName].value;
    if (amount) {
        this.myformname.controls[FormControlName].setValue(amount ? Number(amount).toFixed(2) : 0);
    }
}


Requirements aren't real clear, but I use this for validation of input to 6 decimal places: <input type="text" class="form-control" id="approximateCost"
required pattern="^[0-9]{0,12}([.][0-9]{0,6})?$"
[(ngModel)]="inventoryItem.approximateCost" name="approximateCost"
#approximateCost="ngModel">  You could filter by keyup if needed using similar regex and checking .valid.  "Approximate Cost is required.  Must be number or decimal from 0 to 999999999999.999999." is my validation error.  onfocus="this.select()" will select all onfocus.  So when user types it'll clear.

I Found out that changing my condition will make it workable I change condition like
//Check if input data is not numeric and also control value is not 0 so perform backspace
else if(!/^\d$/.test(inputData) && controlValue != 0) {
control.setValue('');
}

I just twerked my condition a bit for else like
//Check if numput data is not numeric and also control value is not 0 so perform backspace
  else if(!/^\d$/.test(inputData) && controlValue != 0) {
    control.setValue('');
  }


This will allow user to only type numbers, but additionally if input already contains numeric value and user tries to add string or something else than number, value will be set to previus valid one
When User removes last number, input value will be set back to 0.
when User writes first number, 0 will be removed
  <form class="form" [formGroup]="form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="test " formControlName="testname" />
  </form>



  private $destroyRef = new Subject<void>();

  form = new FormGroup({
    testname: new FormControl<number>({ value: 0, disabled: false }),
  });


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form.controls.testname.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.$destroyRef),
        startWith({ oldVal: 0, newVal: 0 }),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        pairwise(),
        map(([oldVal, newVal]) => ({ oldVal, newVal }))
      )
      .subscribe({
        next: (res) => {
          let regexp = /^\d+$/;
          this.form.controls.testname.setValue(
            !regexp.test(String(res.newVal)) ? typeof res.oldVal === 'object'
                ? null
                : res.oldVal === res.oldVal && String(res.oldVal).length === 1
                ? 0
                : Number(res.oldVal)
              : Number(res.newVal)
          );
        },
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.$destroyRef.next();
    this.$destroyRef.complete();
  }

